# Is there any way to get rid of too many polygons in mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, sculpting

I am trying to edit my mesh in edit mode, but because of its polygons numbers, I can barely move the screen. I was sculpting the mesh and applied my multi resolution modifier at level 4... after I figured out my mistake at puting it at 4, I couldn't get the modifier back... is there any way to join meshes?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways that I know of:

1. Using the *Decimate* modifier. It combines near faces that are similar.
   *Un-subdivide* works for me, but you could also use collapse or planar depending on your situations. On *Unsubdivide*, more iteration means less faces.

[image: Decimate Modifier]

2. You could also do a manual re-topology. That's where you go through and manually combine faces.
   I'm not a master at this, so I can't tell you much, but I'm sure there are some great tutorials online about it.

Comment: I did but the face number still does not change

Comment: @BlenderWonder second point will be probably the best method. Most of the time automated ways will not give you desired result.

Comment: Also, at least for me I have to apply the modifier before I can see a change in edit mode.